# How can I install headers using CMake without compilation when the target is a framework?

Tags: cmake

I know how to install headers without compilation when the target is a normal static library, e.g.

```
project(Foo)
add_library(Foo foo.cpp foo.h)
install(FILES foo.h DESTINATION include COMPONENT headers)
add_custom_target(installheaders COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=headers
                 -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake)
```

Calling `make installheaders` will install `foo.h` without actually compiling `Foo`. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do the same thing if `Foo` is a framework, the below is my best attempt

```
project(Foo)
add_library(Foo foo.cpp foo.h)
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES FRAMEWORK TRUE PUBLIC_HEADER "foo.h")
install(FILES foo.h DESTINATION Foo.framework/Versions/A/Headers COMPONENT headers)
add_custom_target(installheaders COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=headers
                 -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake)
```

However, this doesn't work because the symlinks for `foo.h` are missing, meaning there should be a symlink at `Foo.framework/Versions/Current/Headers` and `Foo.framework/Headers`. How can I install headers without compilation when the target is a framework?

Comment: out of curiosity, do you need to list foo.h in the `add_library` if you list it in the `set_target_properties`?

Comment: @user yes it's necessary for the compilation, if foo.h isn't listed in `add_library`, foo.h will not appear in Foo.framework after running `make`.